# stack all levels of a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B'], ['One', 'Two']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(2, 8), columns=index)
df
```

[image]

How do I stack all levels of the `MultiIndex` without knowing how many levels columns has.

I expect the results to look like this:

```
0  a  A  One     0
         Two     1
      B  One     2
         Two     3
   b  A  One     4
         Two     5
      B  One     6
         Two     7
1  a  A  One     8
         Two     9
      B  One    10
         Two    11
   b  A  One    12
         Two    13
      B  One    14
         Two    15
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can first find `len` of levels, get `range` and pass it to [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (df.columns.nlevels)
3

print (list(range(df.columns.nlevels)))
[0, 1, 2]

print (df.stack(list(range(df.columns.nlevels))))
0  a  A  One     0
         Two     1
      B  One     2
         Two     3
   b  A  One     4
         Two     5
      B  One     6
         Two     7
1  a  A  One     8
         Two     9
      B  One    10
         Two    11
   b  A  One    12
         Two    13
      B  One    14
         Two    15
dtype: int32
```

Comment: I did an if/else on `isinstance(df.columns, pd.MultiIndex)`.  I did not know about nlevels.

Comment: Will `df.stack(range(df.columns.nlevels))` fail in python 3?  Notice I removed the call to `list`.

Comment: Yes, it return error `KeyError: 'Level range(0, 3) not found'`

Answer (score 1):

If you name the index levels, you can use the list of names, like this:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B'], ['One', 'Two']], 
    names=['idx1', 'idx2', 'idx3']
)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(2, 8), columns=index)
df.stack(index.names)
```

result:

```
   idx1  idx2  idx3
0  a     A     One      0
               Two      1
         B     One      2
               Two      3
   b     A     One      4
               Two      5
         B     One      6
               Two      7
1  a     A     One      8
               Two      9
         B     One     10
               Two     11
   b     A     One     12
               Two     13
         B     One     14
               Two     15
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hey!  Nice answer. 